# wharf folder on mac

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-space

I was looking into the contents of my MacBookPros disk. While searching for big files I came across a folder called "wharf". It is located in `/Users/username/Library/Application Support/FileProvider/763CD908-3C31-43C2-A740-D5736FFFD7ED` and is roughly 10GB big. Digging deeper I can go into `wharf/wharf/propagate` and find two files each roughly 5GB. File names are cryptic to me: "61403323" and "61403321". Opening them with TextEdit does not give me any hints. One of these files contains lines like

> à'z£¿+\Â¬'©√Û/√R<»7à<Û7G„—ÏPíä)¿=ÑŸ∆˙îÁ∞-€ ú≥®ê≠öjX

**What does this folder contain and can I safely delete it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FileProvider is used by cloud-based systems, like Google Drive, DropBox, and iCloud Drive.

The characters you see in TextEdit would suggest that it's a data file (whose data is just being mapped onto Unicode values).

I don't know exactly what service these files are linked to, nor what they represent. But I would avoid deleting them. They may be removed when the service no longer needs them.

Alternatively: if you have a backup, you can delete anything in your user account, because you can always restore it if there's a problem.

Comment: Thank you. I might try deleting them soon, if they don't disappear.

Comment: Any updates about this issue @X_841? I have the same problem, my wharf/propagate folder is even bigger: 65 GB.

Comment: At some point I just went ahead and deleted the files. Since I had a backup i wasnt too worried, so do that before! I pretty soon forgot about the deletion and dont know what went missing so I guess these files were really some cache or something similar.